# WAV sound plays incorectly in SDL mixer

Tags: audio, sdl, sdl-mixer

Im trying to play these two audio files using SDL. **point_normal.wav** plays correctly while **piecedrop.wav** sound is messed up. IT sounds like radio static.

If I open both files on the Gnome player both play correctly. I tried using ffmpeg to change the bitrate of **piecedrop.wav** to match the one from **pint_normal.wav** unsuccessfully.

Can someone point out what I should do to make sure both sounds are playable by SDL?

### point_normal.wav

```
[FORMAT]
filename=point_normal.wav
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=wav
format_long_name=WAV / WAVE (Waveform Audio)
start_time=N/A
duration=2.242979
size=647140
bit_rate=2308144
probe_score=99
TAG:encoded_by=Logic Pro X
TAG:date=2018-08-05
TAG:creation_time=18:45:48
TAG:time_reference=175060935
TAG:umid=0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080083F0636A9B4B304B305BFF7F00004051030601000000C043305BFF7F0000EC7E1BA3
TAG:coding_history=
[/FORMAT]
```

### piecedrop.wav

```
[FORMAT]
filename=piecedrop.wav
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=wav
format_long_name=WAV / WAVE (Waveform Audio)
start_time=N/A
duration=0.030583
size=282466
bit_rate=73888369
probe_score=99
TAG:encoder=Lavf56.40.101
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: The bit rates are very different. Do you know the format details? How many bits encoding? (16? 24?) Sample rate? (44100? 48000?) One way to tell would be to open them in Audacity, which could also be used to convert the one that doesn't work into a format that SDL can work with.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks! I did exactly that and it worked!